# how to format a random child in an un-ordered list using css

Tags: jquery, css

> how to format random items in an un-ordered list using CSS or JS as shown in the picture
>   [image]

Comment: This, my friend, is called a [wordcloud](http://tagcrowd.com/)

Comment: @Dilver Singh You are suppose to show some code here which you have already tried.

Comment: @sanjay i don't know random css selector

Comment: If you google word cloud you will find that the formatting is not random.

Comment: thanks @Steve, i found the solution

Comment: @DilverSingh if you found the solution, please post the answer here, that may help someone. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/er0j1fv4/

```
<html>

<head> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqcloud/1.0.4/jqcloud.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqcloud/1.0.4/jqcloud-1.0.4.min.js"></script> 
</head> 

<body> 

    <div id="div1" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>


    <script>

  $(document).ready(function(){

      var wordList = [
          {text: "Peter", weight: 15},
          {text: "Martin", weight: 9, link: "http://www.google.com/"},
          {text: "Manhattan", weight: 6, html: {title: "This is the manhattan city"}},
          {text: "Amalie", weight: 7},
          {text: "Himalayas", weight: 5},
          {text: "Peter", weight: 15},
          {text: "Martin", weight: 9, link: "http://www.google.com/"},
          {text: "Manhattan", weight: 6, html: {title: "This is the manhattan city"}},
          {text: "Amalie", weight: 7},
          {text: "Himalayas", weight: 5},
          {text: "Peter", weight: 15},
          {text: "Martin", weight: 9, link: "http://www.google.com/"},
          {text: "Manhattan", weight: 6, html: {title: "This is the manhattan city"}},
          {text: "Amalie", weight: 7},
          {text: "Himalayas", weight: 5},
      ];

        $("#div1").jQCloud(wordList);

  });

    </script>

</body> 

</html>
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Reference:**

> https://github.com/lucaong/jQCloud

Comment: If this helped. Pl, accept as answer.